# Some problems about compactness, connectivity amd arcwise-connectivity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I have some home work about justifying why some sets are compact, connected or arcwise-connected.
The sets are:
$C=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x\in (0,1)\}$
$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0\leq x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$
Now I've already proved that $C$ is not compact (it's open, and by Heine-Borell must be closed to be compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$), and if I can proof that it's arcwise-connected, then is connected, and I think this is true, but I can't find the curve $\alpha : [a,b]\mapsto C$ such that, for every $x,y\in C$:
a) $\alpha(a)=x$
b) $\alpha(b)=y$
c) if $t_k\mapsto t$ then $\alpha(t_k)\mapsto\alpha(t)$
d) $\alpha([a,b])\subset C$.

For $D$, I don't know even if it's compact.
I could use some help here.

Comment: Draw a picture. Place two points in $C$ and link them by a segment. Give a function to describe this segment. For $D$, draw a picture and you will see $D$ is a closed disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C$ is convex, hence it is connected.

$D$ is closed and bounded, hence compact. Moreover it is convex, hence connected.

Comment: but i haven't seen convexity nor bounded properties yet, i don't know how to use that.

Comment: What is compact for you? Closed and bounded? Something else?

Comment: Convexity is just a very special case of being connected in which the path from $x$ to $y$ is a straight segment

Comment: sorry, i forgot Heine-Borell's theorem, so D is compact because of that? Can i bound it with the circumference of radius 1?

Comment: Exactly. Being bounded is precisely saying that the function $x^2+y^2$ is bounded on your set. In the case of $D$, this is by definition.

Comment: Ok, so the curve would be the segment $\alpha(t)=([(y-x)(t-a)]/(b-a)) +x$? for both $C, D$?

Comment: Yes. Usually $\alpha(t)=(1-t)p+tq$ for $t\in[0,1]$ is taken for the line connecting $p$ and $q$. You still have to *check* that the line is contained in $C$/$D$.

Comment: one more question, don't I have trouble here with $\alpha(t)$ like you suggested? Since here it goes from R to R and C is in R^2?

Comment: $\alpha:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$

Comment: sorry, it's because of p,q being taken in R^2?

Comment: Yes, you first fix $p,q\in C$ (or $p,q\in D$) and the join them with a segment. The segment will be a map $[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$